# Output Pure HTML File From R Shiny App

Tags: html, r, shiny

I am looking to deploy my R Shiny App, however I cannot use the standard approach using runapp command and setting the IP to 0.0.0.0. I was wondering if there is any way I can output a pure HTML file that would include both the ui.R as well as the server.R functionality so I can deploy with a pure HTML file that's generated on a daily basis. Is it possible for R/Shiny to produce an index.html file that would include both the ui elements as well as emulate the server.R functionality/reactivity?

Comment: Short answer, no. If you want to deploy an interactive Shiny application, you need to either deploy a [shiny-server](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/shiny-server) or use [shinyapps.io](http://www.shinyapps.io)

Comment: I would add however, you can embed Shiny functionality into documents, such as [rmarkdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_embedded_shiny.html). This may suit your needs.

Comment: I appreciate the reply. Would I be able to use rmarkdown to reference an R Shiny application to output a Rmarkdown file that's pure HTML? What I am getting at is essentially I can run the app on my local machine, but to deploy it to a larger audience I would most likely need a single file that's HTML since where I'm deploying wouldn't have R installed.

Comment: it really depends what the app does. You need to pick the right tool for the job, I use shiny-server on premises and it is a simple thing. [R Notebooks](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/r_notebooks.html#saving_and_sharing) are self contained `html` with the `R` code embedded for reproducibility. They can be opened and edited as `.Rmd` files easily if you use the RStudio IDE. However, they will become very large very quickly after embedding data and any other assets to support it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Basically, @Kevin Arschenau already pointed out the most impportant points in his comments.

You need an R server in order to execute a shiny app. There is no way to convert it into "pure HTML" and run the interactivity via javascript. The reason for that is that shiny apps will have to execute R code at runtime and javascript does not know how to deal with that.

If the site you want to deploy to does not have a working installation of R (and `shiny-server`), the only way to display a shiny app there is hosting the app on a different server and embedding it (via an iframe). For example, you can upload an app on [shinyapps.io](http://www.shinyapps.io) and include it in your webpage as demonstrated [here](http://www.open-meta.org/technology/shiny/see-your-shiny-app-inside-wordpress-with-iframes/).

If your company does not allow you to host the app on third-party sites (for disclosure reasons), you will have to consult the IT department and ask them to

- install `R` and `shiny-server` on your company's server or
- give you a VM or docker container so you can install the dependencies there

In case of docker, there are certain projects that facilitate this process. For example, [shinyproxy](https://www.shinyproxy.io/) makes it easy to create scalable apps with LDAP authentication.

If `shiny-server` is used directly by your company, note that there are user-limits in the free version.

### Follow up from 5 years later

There is now "shiny for pyhon" availabe which allows you to deploy apps in a "serverless" manner. This is possible by running pyhon on the client side via webassembly. See [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/py/docs/shinylive.html) for more details. I wouldn't recommend to rewrite existing apps using another language but still think it is worth mentioning here.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If I get a Linux server can i just install R and have that instance act as the server or would I need shiny server too?

Comment: You need `shiny-server` as far as i know. Installation instructions for `Ubuntu 14.04 x64` can be found [here](http://deanattali.com/2015/05/09/setup-rstudio-shiny-server-digital-ocean/)

Comment: A correction for my last comment: if you take a look at the [dockerfiles from golem](https://github.com/ThinkR-open/golem/blob/7a9debb1fab42368ee3b50803483416180508c6f/R/add_dockerfiles.R#L181-L188) you actually see that they deploy apps without installing `shiny-server`.